# Convert PDF to grayscale on Linux, *without adding transparency*

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript

I have a color PDF which doesn't use transparency. I would like to convert it to a grayscale PDF **also without transparency** on Linux.

The common answer to converting a PDF to grayscale is to use GhostScript:

```
gs \
  -o grayscale.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray\
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
  color.pdf
```

The problem is that this results in a PDF with transparency, which is claimed not to be supported properly by my target downstream process (printing by a POD vendor).

The obvious seeming solution is to just decrease the output PDF version to 1.3 which doesn't support transparency:

```
gs \
  -o grayscale-1.3.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray\
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 \
  color.pdf
```

Unfortunately, this results in a rasterized PDF, which is something I would also like to avoid.

I am not married to GhostScript, any other solution that works on Linux is in scope.

Comment: First thing I'd do is to open the PDF (you can do that in a text editor), using `mutools` to decompress streams if necessary, and have a look at what's actually going, and how the transparency (alpha channel?) manifests itself in the conversion output. Possibly you can just turn the alpha channel off by modifying some nodes of the PDF.